# How to avoid exceptions when providing a ClaimsProviderSelection after login?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying implement a flow which allows a user to select from one of several verification options, using an `<OrchestractionStop Type="ClaimsProviderSelection"...>`

My flow works as expected when I specify only a single `<ClaimsProviderSelection>`, but when I specify multiple `<ClaimsProviderSelections>` my B2C flow crashes with a generic "AADB2C: An exception occured." message.

How should I correctly provide multiple claims providers?

*Edit: Update*

This seems to be linked to how I sign in the users in prevous steps: If I run a local account sign in  and AAD profile read (from the base polices) after my own claims provider selection, everything works as expected. If I don't sign in the user at all, everything also works as expected. The issue only happens if I log in the user before the `ClaimsProviderSelection` step.

*Edit: Details*

The crash occurs when the IDP selection is due to be presented to the user, before the selection is actually shown.

The data URI for the `api.idpselection` content definition is `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0`.

**Code:**

*This works*:

```
  <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvider">
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertPassportVerification" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertPassportVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-PassportVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

*This works:*

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvider">
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-DLVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

*This does not work:*

```
  <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvider">
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertPassportVerification" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertPassportVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-PassportVerification" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-DLVerification" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: You have a typo in DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvier" and I'm wodering if that should be set to that value, if you're trying to show multiple.

Comment: Thank you, @Adam. That's just a transcription error in my code here. I'll edit the question to correct it. According [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#claimsproviderselection) the attribute only has effects when a single option is present, and `ShowSingleProvider` is the only accepted value.

In any case I've tried with this attribute removed completely and observed the same problem.

Comment: Hi Iris, can you please show us what content definition DataUri you are using for api.idpselections? Also, can you tell us where in the flow it crashes? Does it crash as soon as you execute the policy? Or does it crash when you click on an IDP selection?

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherNorris.

The flow crashes once it reaches the would-be `ClaimsProviderSelection` step, before the IDP selections are presented. My `DataUri` for the `api.idpselections` definition is `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0`.

Comment: @iris-HP would you be open to having a conversation about this and showing more of your code? I find this to be an interesting problem.

Comment: @ChristoperNorris. I'll get back to you on that one. For now I've filed a bug report with MS - I figure either their documentation or implementation is wrong (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/68117). If they can't provide any more insight, I'll look at providing a redacted version of some of our polices for discussion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvider">
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertPassportVerification" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsProviderSelections DisplayOption="ShowSingleProvider">
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertPassportVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-PassportVerification" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertDriversLicenseVerification" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Self-Assert-DLVerification" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. The first `ClaimsProviderSelection` fires the first verification option, and then jumps to the next step, 4, never to return.

This feels like a bug in B2C the more I play with it: Having a `ClaimsProviderSelection` step after a `CombinedSignInAndSIgnUp` step causes an error - amusingly if I do this the other way around - get the identity document credentials from the user before I prompt for login, everything just works as expected... but is counterintuitivve from a user's point of view.